# Invoke a browser page on HELP in a MESSAGEBOX

Tags: .net, vb6

I have some VB6 code and am showing message boxes in it. Now I want to add a HELP button in the message box. VB6 provides a way to do it and invoke a help file (.hlp, .chm). However, I want to invoke a browser page in the Help. 
I could not achieve the same.

My VB6 code is something like this.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
     i = MsgBox("Hello World", vbInformation + vbMsgBoxHelpButton, "Title", "http://www.google.com", 1) 
End Sub
```

I have realized that it does load google in the windows HTML viewer. So if the page is static it will work fine. But if the page has some videos or if I want to open a Youtube video then i am stuck

However, I tried the same in VB.Net and I could use the messageBox.show function to invoke the dialog and on clicking the help button, it launched the default browser and opened the page.

```
Public Function DisplayMessage(message As String, prompt As String,
                buttons As MessageBoxButtons, icons As MessageBoxIcon,
                defaultButton As MessageBoxDefaultButton,
                options As MessageBoxOptions, HelpURL As String) As Integer 
    Dim x As Integer
    x = MessageBox.Show(message, prompt, buttons, icons, defaultButton, 0, HelpURL)
    Return x
End Function
```

I made an INTEROP assembly of the project and tried to invoke from VB6. The dialog would show, but the HELP button would do nothing.

What am I missing?
Can someone help me.

Thanks

Comment: Please show your code. Not the whole thing, but all the relevant parts. You can EDIT the question and add this.

Comment: Edit the question to add these details, its very hard to read as a comment.

Comment: According to the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show?view=netcore-3.1) you need to create a delegate for  HelpRequested event. Take a look at the example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.helprequested?view=netcore-3.1#examples